# Preciso selecionar sequencias de números em um campo de uma coluna da tabela

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, regex, query, select

Eu tenho uma coluna 'Text' na minha tabela 'process'. Text consiste em um VARCHAR (220), neste texto eu preciso identificar um padrão específico de palavra. Neste caso uma seqüência de números com um "-" para separar:


**'1234-567'** - São 4 Dígitos seguidos de '-' e logo após 3 Dígitos;


E antes deste número há uma palavra como 'ProNumber: '.
Então eu tentei usar a função Substring e Locate, para rastrear e mostrar o resultado.

`SELECT substring(Texto, locate('ProNumber:', Texto) +11,8) como número FROM processo;`

Mas infelizmente este número aparece várias vezes no campo da coluna 'Text', e minha consulta apenas mostra o primeiro.
Existe alguma maneira de fazer uma consulta que retorna os vários números que o campo contém?


Editado:

Gostaria que o resultado fosse algo do tipo:

 **Process | ProNumber**

    0001    | 1234-567

    0001    | 8945-567

    0002    | 1258-567

    0003    | 1454-547

    0004    | 1548-987

    0004    | 1234-567

Comment: Sua questão está um pouco confusa. Você quer fazer um filtro (`WHERE`) que encontre os registros com esse padrão numérico ou quer ter uma saída no `SELECT` que retire do texto alguns caracteres que não estejam nesse padrão?

Comment: Me desculpe, O que eu estou querendo é que o resultado do Select seja uma coluna, em mostre as sequências de números, contidos no campo. No meio do campo podem existir por exemplo 3 dessas sequências, gostaria que as 3 fossem retornadas pelo Select.

Comment: Olá, adicione por favor alguns registros de exemplo e a saída exata (resultado do SELECT) que você precisa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente usar esse padrão de regex para capturar o que você precisa.

```
([\n]|^)(?=ProNumber: (\d*-\d*)*)
```

Como você não especificou se o numero de dígitos contido na sequencia "123-456" pode variar deixei a regex delimitada somente pela sequencia "ProNumber: " colocando um `positivelookahead` mas aconselho você a delimitar pelo numero de caracteres antes e depois de "-" se forem valores fixos, evitando capturas indesejadas.

Comment: Sim, são valores fixos! Tanto de antes do "-" quanto depois. Precisaria que estes  valores fossem entregues pelo próprio Select. Para cada Processo que todos os números contidos no campo Texto fossem exibidos.